# How can I detect the maximum value in several rows and columns at the same time in an SQL table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which records values over time, similar to the following:

[image]

The next value after the zero value indicates the beginning of the highest value to one case for a given time.
Example: To Time6 the maximum value is 5 because only case4 Start (after zero value) in that moment the others continuing decreasing at that time.

I need to know at a given moment what is the maximum value case for all the times shown and gradually place it as shown in the following table:

[image]

I have worked with some of the aggregate and analytic functions, but can't seem to find the correct solution especially because query is to a table of 40 million records. 
I hope an SQL expert guru can help me out, or at least point me in the right direction or some efficient algorithm. Is there a way to query this (preferably without a cursor?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you are trying to do correctly then this should work ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7cbf4b361073486ad8a218baedfaea9b)).

The `CASE` expression ensures that only values with `0` in the preceding column are considered for the aggregation. Prior to the aggregation the integers (presumed >= 0) are padded out with leading zeroes to make them exactly 10 characters long and concatenated to the `Cases` string.

The `MAX` is then found to get the lexicographically greatest concatenated string for that time (as [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/optimizing-top-n-group-queries)) and then this is split into its constituent parts.

In the event that there is more than one eligible row with the same maximum value for a specific time this will somwehat arbitrarily pick the one with the alphabetically latest `Cases` string

```
WITH Grouped As
(
SELECT [ID], 
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Time2] = 0 THEN FORMAT([Time3],'D10') + [Cases] END) AS TC3, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Time3] = 0 THEN FORMAT([Time4],'D10') + [Cases] END) AS TC4, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Time4] = 0 THEN FORMAT([Time5],'D10') + [Cases] END) AS TC5, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Time5] = 0 THEN FORMAT([Time6],'D10') + [Cases] END) AS TC6, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Time6] = 0 THEN FORMAT([Time7],'D10') + [Cases] END) AS TC7, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Time7] = 0 THEN FORMAT([Time8],'D10') + [Cases] END) AS TC8, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Time8] = 0 THEN FORMAT([Time9],'D10') + [Cases] END) AS TC9
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [ID]
)
SELECT [ID], 
       Time3 = 0+LEFT(TC3,10),
       Cases3 = SUBSTRING(TC3,11,8000),
       Time4 = 0+LEFT(TC4,10),
       Cases4 = SUBSTRING(TC4,11,8000),
       Time5 = 0+LEFT(TC5,10),
       Cases5 = SUBSTRING(TC5,11,8000),
       Time6 = 0+LEFT(TC6,10),
       Cases6 = SUBSTRING(TC6,11,8000),
       Time7 = 0+LEFT(TC7,10),
       Cases7 = SUBSTRING(TC7,11,8000),
       Time8 = 0+LEFT(TC8,10),
       Cases8 = SUBSTRING(TC8,11,8000),
       Time9 = 0+LEFT(TC9,10),
       Cases9 = SUBSTRING(TC9,11,8000)
FROM Grouped
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't know how will you create such table dynamically, but for now I created table only with 5 Time columns for testing

```
CREATE TABLE times (id int IDENTITY (1,1),Cases varchar(5),Time1 int,Time2 int,Time3 int,Time4 int, Time5 int)

INSERT INTO times VALUES ('CASE1',8,0,10,9,8),('CASE2',2,1,0,0,8),('CASE3',5,4,0,7,6),('CASE4',0,5,0,5,0),('CASE5',4,0,0,9,8),('CASE6',0,6,0,0,6)
```

I know you not prefer loops, but I think it'll help you somehow

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Times varchar(100),Cases varchar(100),Value int)
DECLARE @time_min_nr varchar(1)=1, --Times column minimum value
@time_max_nr varchar(3)=5, --Times column maximum value
@time_big_nr varchar(3),
@query nvarchar(1000)
WHILE @time_min_nr<@time_max_nr
BEGIN
SET @time_big_nr=@time_min_nr+1
SET @query='INSERT INTO #temp SELECT TOP 1 ''Time'+@time_big_nr+''' Times,Cases,MAX(Time'+@time_big_nr+')-MIN(TIME'+@time_min_nr+') Value  FROM times GROUP BY Cases ORDER BY Value DESC'
EXEC sp_executesql @query
SET @time_min_nr+=1
END
SELECT * FROM #temp
```